# Linq Query two table with like on condition

Tags: c#, sql, linq, join

I am trying to join two tables to know if the first table data has a like value from the second table. I tried to use it in `SQL` and it worked perfectly.

Please see sample below

```
select  * from Table_1 t1 left outer join
    Table_2 t2 on t1.a like '% ' + t2.a + ' %' or t1.a like '' + t2.a + ' %' or t1.a like '% ' + t2.a + ''
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get the result you are expecting:

```
var query= from t1 in Table_1 
           from t2 in Table_2
           //Your first condition include the rest, you don't need them
           where t1.a.Contains(t2.a) //|| t1.a.StartWith(t2.a) ||  t1.a.EndsWith(t2.a)
           select new {t1,t2};
```

Comment: Thank you for the help @octavioccl this helps me a lot. :) and it works perfectly.

Comment: You're welcome @KyleLeonor, If you think my answer helped you to solve your question, please, consider mark the question as answered clicking the checkmark